# Communication between infected machines via listening to certain port

Tags: network, malware, ports

Are there any detailed case-studies in which infected machines in a certain network or on the internet were communication with each other (I'm not interested in cases with only machine <-> C&C communications)?

E.g.: PC-A gets infected, then infects PC-B etc... PC-A and maybe others open a port and then the infected machines communicate with each other (and maybe with the C&C as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you expect precisely when you ask for *"detailed case-studies"*, but if PC-B has no Internet access, it is a well-known practice for the attacker to use PC-A as a relay between PC-B and the C&C:

```
PC-B <---> PC-A <---> C&C
```

To give a more concrete example:

1. PC-A belongs to the users LAN, this is the computer where people access to their emails and browse the Web. Sadly, one email or web page was infected, thus contaminating PC-A.
2. Once in running in the LAN, either in an autonomous way or remotely controlled by the C&C, the virus starts to scan the network and try to propagate itself. It reaches PC-B (unpatched vulnerability, poor password or whatever) and contaminates it.
3. PC-B belongs to another, restricted network with no access to the Internet (with chances that it has access to more interesting resources!). The virus can setup a way for PC-B to use PC-A as a relay to get new orders from the C&C and exfiltrate data.

This relay can take any form depending on the attacker fantasy and requirements. It can range from simple proxy-like features to a full fledged peer-to-peer network ensuring that the virus' network will remain functional even if some relay machines are being decontaminated.

Comment: By _detailed case-studies_ I mean papers/documents by security researchers that describe such techniques in the wild.

Comment: @ENG: You will find such techniques mostly in state sponsored espionage software as they are costly to design and implement. Two good examples may be [Uroburos](https://public.gdatasoftware.com/Web/Content/INT/Blog/2014/02_2014/documents/GData_Uroburos_RedPaper_EN_v1.pdf) (see the intro and page 9 "Network capabilities", attributed to Russia) and [Regin](http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/media/security_response/whitepapers/regin-analysis.pdf) (see page 16 "Topology", attributed to US and/or UK).

Comment: I would add this to the answer as those are good examples : )